# "Error: ValidationError: duration: Cast to Number failed for value \"NaN\" at path \"duration\"

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, npm, mongoose

im trying to update a data from database(mongoodb), but when im trying to check it on Postman, i get this error: 
"Error: ValidationError: duration: Cast to Number failed for value \"NaN\" at path \"duration\", date: Cast to date failed for value \"NaN\" at path \"date\", username: Path `username` is required., description: Path `description` is required."

This is my route:

```
const router = require('express').Router();
let Exercise = require('../models/exercise.model');

router.route('/').get((req, res) =>{
Exercise.find()
    .then(exercises => res.json(exercises))
    .catch(err => res.status(400).json('Error: ' + err));
});

router.route('/add').post((req, res) =>{
const   username    = req.body.username,
        description = req.body.description,
        duration    = Number(req.body.duration),
        date        = Date.parse(req.body.date);

const newExercise = new Exercise({
    username,
    description,
    duration,
    date,
});

newExercise.save()
    .then(() => res.json('Exercise added!'))
    .catch(err => res.status(400).json('Error: ' + err));
});

// See the Information of exercises in the database
router.route('/:id').get((req, res) =>{
Exercise.findById(req.params.id)
    .then(exercises => res.json(exercises))
    .catch(err => res.status(400).json('Error: ' + err));
});

// Delete exercises from the database
router.route('/:id').delete((req, res) =>{
Exercise.findByIdAndDelete(req.params.id)
    .then(() =>res.json('Exercise was deleted!'))
    .catch(err =>  res.status(400).json('Error: ' + err));
});

// Update the exercise to the database
router.route('/update/:id').post((req, res) => {
Exercise.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id)
  .then(exercise => {
    exercise.username = req.body.username;
    exercise.description = req.body.description;
    exercise.duration = Number(req.body.duration);
    exercise.date = Date.parse(req.body.date);
    console.log(typeof(exercise.date));

    exercise.save()
      .then(() => res.json('Exercise updated!'))
      .catch(err => res.status(400).json('Error: ' + err));
  })
  .catch(err => res.status(400).json('Error: ' + err));
 });

 // Export the route
 module.exports = router;
```

And this is my Schema:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const exerciseSchema = new Schema({
username: {type: String, required: true},
description: {type: String, required: true},
duration: {type: Number, required: true},
date: {type: Date, required: true},
}, {
timestamps: true,
});

const Exercise = mongoose.model('Exercise', exerciseSchema);

module.exports = Exercise;
```

Please help me to solve this problem, Thank you

Comment: According to your `Schema` all the fields are marked as `required: true`. Looks like the `username`, `duration` ... fields are not present in the `req.body`

Comment: What should i do? sorry i'm new in mongoose

Comment: Can you please update the question with a sample request body that is been sent from the postman

Comment: "Error: ValidationError: duration: Cast to Number failed for value \"NaN\" at path \"duration\", date: Cast to date failed for value \"NaN\" at path \"date\", username: Path `username` is required., description: Path `description` is required."

Comment: This is the `response` that you get in postman. Are you passing any request JSON body while making the `POST` call from the postman

Comment: Yeah, im passing. request JSON body while making post request from postman. I don't know why it's wrong!

Comment: Just do a `console.log(req.body)` and make sure you are receiving it in your application

Answer (score 0):

In the update block you are using findByIdAndUpdate,
replace that with findById
or if you are going to use findByIdAndUpdate then provide all the update details in arguments

```
findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, {
  username = req.body.username,
  description = req.body.description,
  duration = Number(req.body.duration),
  date = Date.parse(req.body.date),
}, 
function(err,docs){
   if(err) console.log(err)
   else console.log("Updated")
})
```

or if using fingById

```
Exercise.findById(req.params.id)
   .then(exercise => {
        exercise.username = req.body.username,
        exercise.description = req.body.description,
        exercise.duration = Number(req.body.duration),
        exercise.date = Date.parse(req.body.date)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Just had this issue with Postman and it was because I forgot to change the raw body type from `Text` to `JSON`. Even though it was valid JSON being sent the type of the raw data wasn't correct.